# I have some slow-cooked pork in the freezer and just need to warm it up

Tags: meat, reheating, thawing

I slow-cooked this meat about six months ago and had a lot left over which
went into the freezer in a tightly-wrapped plastic bag.  It does not really
matter now when I eat it, but I do want the quality to be as good as
possible (and I want to eat it in a sandwich with the meat at least a
little warm).

So, thinking about quality, how should I get this meat warm?

Conventional thinking is to let the meat unfreeze over two days in
the refrigerator and then warm it (maybe over 15 minutes) in a covered
pan with a little water added.

An alternative might be to just go directly from freezer to covered
pan and give it lower heat for a longer time (maybe over 60 minutes).

Or is there a better approach?  Is there a secret here or does it taste
the same either way?

One reason I'm thinking that the "alternative" above might be better is
because, when freezing meat, we want to freeze it as quickly as possible
to avoid large ice crystal formation (which affects the taste).  So, it
seems natural to do the reverse process as quickly as possible too.  But,
the trade-off then might be that a fast-reheating method will tend to
burn the outside and leave the inside cool.  Still, if the frozen meat
were stored in a thin enough layer, the "alternative" above seems better.

By the way, I think [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/99043)
is more about thawing raw meat.  It seems to indicate that there really is
not a noticeable difference, so I suspect the same here in the already-cooked
case...but I wanted to ask because I really want to eat this pork.

Answer (score 4):

**Hair of the dog?**

You got a slow cooker.  And this meat has been in there before.  Putting it back in the slow cooker will do it no harm and will get some good juice back in.

Comment: You mean directly from the freezer?  Warm, low, or high setting on slow cooker?

Comment: Right from the freezer.  High setting.  I am hungry!